# Tableview drag and drop a song in a row to a playlist button on the side bar javafx

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx, tableview

I have a javafx TableView populated with a class called Song. I have a sidebar in my border pane populated with Buttons that represent a class called Playlist.  my (currently basic) UI looks like this: 
[image: My UI]

I want to make it so that if I drag a song and drop it in to one of the buttons on the left, it adds that song to the playlist. Also I have looked and searched around the internet for an answer and haven't found anything useful.  That being said, please don't link me to something. I have already tried implementing the code from the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm#CHDJFJDH 
If you have any suggestions please help me! thanks!

UPDATE:
Here's my code, my naming conventions are pretty easily understandable:

```
    musicTable.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { //click
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) { // double click

                Song selected =   (Song)musicTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                dragged = selected;
                if (selected != null) {
                    System.out.println("select : " + selected);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    musicTable.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { //drag
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            // drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture
            Song selected = (Song)musicTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            dragged = selected;
            if (selected != null) {

                Dragboard db = musicTable.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(selected.pointer.toString());
                db.setContent(content);
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });

    musicTable.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            // data is dragged over the target
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    });
    musicTable.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {

                String text = db.getString();
                //tableContent.add(text);
                //musicTable.setItems(tableContent);

                success = true;
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        }
    });
    playlistTable.setRowFactory(cb -> {
        TableRow<Playlist> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
            musicTable.setItems(row.getItem().playlist);

            row.setOnDragDropped( new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                    boolean success = false;

                    row.getItem().add(dragged);
                    System.out.println("ACCEPED TRANSFER");

                    success = true;

                    event.setDropCompleted(success);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
        });
        return row;

    });
```

dragged is a song that keeps track of which song is being dragged, if you have any other way of doing that please tell me, musicTable is what I'm dragging from, playlist table is where I'm dragging to.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to implement it as shown in the tutorial?

Comment: Nothing happened. Like nothing moved

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the smallest example I could create:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    ObservableList<String> tableData = FXCollections
            .observableList(IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    TableView<String> stringTable = new TableView<>(tableData);

    TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>();
    column1.setCellValueFactory(cb -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cb
            .getValue()));
    stringTable.getColumns().add(column1);

    stringTable.setRowFactory(cb -> {
        TableRow<String> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnDragDetected(ev -> {
            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(row.getItem());
            db.setContent(content);

            ev.consume();
        });
        return row;
    });

    VBox leftSide = new VBox();
    leftSide.setPrefWidth(300);

    leftSide.setOnDragOver(ev -> {
        if (ev.getGestureSource() != leftSide && ev.getDragboard().hasString()) {
            ev.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        }
        ev.consume();
    });

    leftSide.setOnDragDropped(ev -> {
        Dragboard db = ev.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasString()) {
            Label label = new Label(db.getString());
            leftSide.getChildren().add(label);
            success = true;
        }
        ev.setDropCompleted(success);
        ev.consume();
    });

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(stringTable);
    root.setLeft(leftSide);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This is a BorderPane where the center is a `TableView` and the left side is a `VBox`.

Now I added your requested Drag and Drop handlers so you can drag rows (thus this is done in the [row factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#rowFactoryProperty--)) to the left side, where they are added as new `Label`s to the `VBox` as new children.

---

**Edit: Second example** with `ListView` as drop target:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ObservableList<String> tableData = FXCollections
            .observableList(IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    TableView<String> stringTable = new TableView<>(tableData);

    TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>();
    column1.setCellValueFactory(cb -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cb
            .getValue()));
    stringTable.getColumns().add(column1);

    stringTable.setRowFactory(cb -> {
        TableRow<String> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnDragDetected(ev -> {
            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(row.getItem());
            db.setContent(content);

            ev.consume();
        });
        return row;
    });

    ObservableList<String> leftSideItems = FXCollections
            .observableList(IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    ListView<String> leftSideDropTarget = new ListView<String>(
            leftSideItems);
    leftSideDropTarget.setPrefWidth(200);
    leftSideDropTarget.setCellFactory(cb -> {
        ListCell<String> cell = new TextFieldListCell<>();

        cell.setOnDragOver(ev -> {
            if (ev.getGestureSource() != cell
                    && ev.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                ev.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            }
            ev.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragDropped(ev -> {
            Dragboard db = ev.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                cell.setText("Got Item: " + db.getString());
                success = true;
            }
            ev.setDropCompleted(success);
            ev.consume();
        });

        return cell;

    });

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(stringTable);
    root.setLeft(leftSideDropTarget);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hey @eckig thanks for your proposal but this doesn't really solve my issue.  I want to be able to drag a song from one table into an already existing playlist in another table. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is just an example.. you can easily replace the target `VBox` with a `TableView` and instead of adding a new `Label` you can add something to the data of a `TableView`. There is no additional magic needed, its all here.

Comment: Well doesn't the playlist table need a row factory?

Comment: Look at the code I have up there at the playlisttable.setRowFactory, it's not working, how would i fix the that?

Comment: As I said: Don' t do it the row factory, instead do `playlistTable.setOnDragOver()` etc. You need the row factory only for the source of the DnD operation.

Comment: Then how do I know which row it's being dropped in to? Is that the job of the ev variable? Actually I'm pretty sure ev is for the event correct?

Comment: If I don't get the row of playlistTable then I don't know which playlist to add the song into

Comment: See my edit.. To simplify things I used a ListView instead of a TableView (and I think that is what you should use on the left side)

Comment: Hey eckig, I'm trying out that method right now, how would I do the following with ListView: `musicTable.setItems(row.getItem().playlist);` and make it so that it displays the playlists name in the sidebar rather than tons of items?

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark this answer correctly. If you have more questions, please post them separately - the comments section is not the right place for that ;-)

Comment: Haha very true, I actually worked it out though! Thanks so much man! Great idea to use list view! that basically fixed all of my issues haha